# "don't fit me" versus "don't suit me"

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct?

"Green and orange don't fit me" or "Green and orange don't suit me"

Answer (score 1):

"Green and orange don't suit me" is correct because you are speaking of colours. "fit me" would be used when speaking of clothes.

Comment: So would *suit me*. I think you mean *when speaking of sizes*.